# Xetex - sorting in a table

Tags: tables, xetex, sorting

I have a table which has several columns, among them

```
    |Col. A|...|...|Col. B|...|Col. C|...|
```

I want to print the table 3 times, one time sorted according to Col. A, next to Col. B, next to Col. C.
At the moment I am doing this with the help of MSExcel and insert the sorted tables into my code. But it should also be possible with nomencl, since nomencl sorts lists.

My minimum example:

```
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \\
    ... & HZL & Unicode & Name & ...& ...& ...& ... \\
    ... & 124 & 1279F   & GER  & ..& ...& ...& ... \\
    ... & 113 & 1259F   & mur  & ...& ...& ...& ... \\
    \end{tabular}
```

HZL=Col.A, Unicode=Col.B, Name=Col.C

Since this takes place in the framework of a Hittite couse, the table will have to be sorted every week when new signs are added. The tabular environment will actually be an evironment for longer tables (longtabular or supertabular). I am using XeTex.I saw the ExcelToLatex possibility, but then I end up having to copy three tables into my code every week, that is quite unelegant. What I want is something like:

```
    \def\tabentry124{... & 124 & 1279F   & GER  & ..& ...& ...& ... \\}
    \def\tabeentry113{... & 113 & 1259F   & mur  & ...& ...& ...& ... \\}
    \begin{tabular}
    \tabentry113
    \tabentry124
    \end{tabular}
```

This code would even save me one sorting procedure, since the entries would already be sorted according to the HZL number.

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Angelika

Comment: Probably you can make use of `pgfplotstable`.

Comment: Hm, looks not bad. I just downloaded the manual, will get into it. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small example on how you could use `pgfplotstable` in order to sort your table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableset{col sep=semicolon, string type}
\pgfplotstableread
{
HZL;Unicode;Name     
124;1279F  ;GER
113;1259F  ;mu
}\loadedtable

sort by "HZL" column:

\pgfplotstabletypeset[sort,sort cmp={int <},sort key=HZL]\loadedtable

\bigskip
sort by "Unicode" column:

\pgfplotstabletypeset[sort,sort cmp={string <},sort key=Unicode]\loadedtable

\bigskip
sort by "Name" column:

\pgfplotstabletypeset[sort,sort cmp={string <},sort key=Name]\loadedtable

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works!! :-) Thanks a lot for this example. Let's hope it also works for large tables: at the end it will have 300+ lines.

Comment: @Fuzzy: According to the documentation, `pgfplotstable` also supports `longtable`. For an example, see page 23 of the documentation.)

Comment: That's what I will need! Thanks for the hint. I will start pottering tonight!